# How to use JSON_VALUE with a variable

Tags: json, oracle

I have a statement I'm trying to construct in Oracle 18c.  The following line works fine:

```
Select JSON_VALUE(l_resp, '$.items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].type')
  into l_temp_var
  from dual;
```

However, I have to vary the second index by a variable.  The second index currently contains `[1]`.  I  tried using `[i]` defined as a numeric or varchar, but that doesn't work.  How can I construct a `Select JSON_VALUE` statement so that it uses a variable?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make the concatenation work.  I tried another approach.  I had to put the "type" and "identifier" into a Json table.

```
    --Obtain the NVP values of "industryIdentifiers" e.g. ISBN_10, ISBN_13 .
    For rowz in 
        (select *
            from json_table(l_resp, '$.items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[*]' 
                            columns (ii_type varchar2(512) path '$.type',
                                     ii_identifier varchar2(512) path '$.identifier'
                                     ) 
                            ) j_ii_tab
        )
    Loop
/*
    If rowz.ii_type = 'ISBN_10' Then
        :P133_ISBN_10 := rowz.ii_identifier;
    Elsif rowz.ii_type = 'ISBN_13' Then
        :P133_ISBN_13 := rowz.ii_identifier;
    End If ;
*/    
    dbms_output.put_line('ii_type: ' || rowz.ii_type);
    dbms_output.put_line('ii_identifier: ' || rowz.ii_identifier);
    End Loop rowz;
```

It might be helpful to see the Json data at: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781484204856

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatination to build your index string. For example:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    Select JSON_VALUE(l_resp, '$.items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[' || i || '].type')
      into l_temp_var
      from dual;

    -- Do something with the value in l_temp_var here

  END LOOP;
END:
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Bob.  That didn't work.  I also tried:         l_ind_iden_sql := '$.items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[' || rowz.rn || '].type';
        SELECT JSON_VALUE(l_resp, l_ind_iden_sql) 
        into l_temp_var 
        from dual;  That didn't work either.